# Which star wars D6 campaign set contains the blueprints / floorplans for a Corellian corvette?

Tags: product-identification, star-wars-d6

I remeember that one D6 supplement had complete floorplans for a corellian corvette but not which one. As far as I remember it was so that the campaign set had detailed infos about an introductionary adventure where you captured the corvette in question and then set off to unknown regions of the galaxy.

My question would be which campaign set it was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the *[DarkStryder Campaign box set](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_DarkStryder_Campaign)*. This campaign featured a map of the (modified) corvette Far Star, and detailed it's adventures in the Kathol Outback.